# CSS Flexbox not stacking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a problem with some CSS, I have 3 news columns that I want to stack when the screen gets less wide then 1024px. However, with the code, I've got right now they just disappear. Strangely I've got 2 of these rows that need to stack, one called `.row` which is working and one called `.newsrow` which is not working.

CSS:

```
/*Neccasary for alignment for some reason, have to solve this issue later*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*Style van overall body*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}
/*Style voor h2 tekst*/
h2 {

}

/* Style the header */
.header {
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Container for flexboxes */
.row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.contentrow {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

/* 3 middelse columns (Grootte wordt bepaald in html doc (Standaard: Flex-Grow: 4;)) */
.column {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.middlemenu {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Container for newsboxes */
.newsrow {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.newsbox {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 225px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #999999;
    }

/* Style van de footer. */
.footer {
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Zorgt ervoor dat bij het krimpen de flexboxes stapelen i.p.v. naast elkaar blijven staan.*/
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .row {
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      display: block;
    }

    .newsrow {
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      display: flex;    
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h2>234234</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#444; padding: 10px;">1337 WHEH</div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#555; flex-grow: 4;">
        <div class="middlemenu" style="background-color:#777">
            <!--Hier komt menu content-->
        </div>
        <div class="newsrow">
            <div class="newsbox"></div>
            <div class="newsbox"></div>
            <div class="newsbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#666; padding: 10px;">1337 WHEEEH</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue:
When I make the screen smaller everything within `.row` stacks on top of each other instead of side by side. However, everything in `.newsrow` just disappears once it reaches the width of 1023px.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Simply remove `height` on the `.column`

Comment: I tried that and even tho that solved another one of my problems, they'll still disappear instead of stack.

Comment: That's unusual.. they stack for me in the answer below. Do you have any additional code that might be interfering?

Comment: I'll edit my post with the code as it looks right now. It's all the code I have xD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the height of the columns, look at this example

```css
/*Neccasary for alignment for some reason, have to solve this issue later*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.contentrow {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

/* 3 middelse columns (Grootte wordt bepaald in html doc (Standaard: Flex-Grow: 4;)) */
.column {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.middlemenu {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Container for newsboxes */
.newsrow {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.newsbox {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
    }

/* Zorgt ervoor dat bij het krimpen de flexboxes stapelen i.p.v. naast elkaar blijven staan.*/
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .row {
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .newsrow {
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;  
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:red; padding: 10px;">1337 WHEH</div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:blue; flex-grow: 4;">
        <div class="middlemenu" style="background-color:orange">
            <!--Hier komt menu content-->
        </div>
        <div class="newsrow">
            <div class="newsbox">lIn velit voluptate </div>
            <div class="newsbox">asa<div>
            <div class="newsbox">asdas</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:green; padding: 10px;">112389127389721 WHEEEH</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height` property on `.column`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/rvjs827p/1/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Style van overall body*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}


/*Style voor h2 tekst*/

h2 {}


/* Style the header */

.header {
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Container for flexboxes */

.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.contentrow {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}


/* 3 middelse columns (Grootte wordt bepaald in html doc (Standaard: Flex-Grow: 4;)) */

.column {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  /* remove this */
  /* height: 300px; */
  text-align: center;
}

.middlemenu {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Container for newsboxes */

.newsrow {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.newsbox {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 225px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #999999;
}


/* Style van de footer. */

.footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Zorgt ervoor dat bij het krimpen de flexboxes stapelen i.p.v. naast elkaar blijven staan.*/

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .row {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .newsrow {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>234234</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#444; padding: 10px;">1337 WHEH</div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#555; flex-grow: 4;">
    <div class="middlemenu" style="background-color:#777">
      <!--Hier komt menu content-->
    </div>
    <div class="newsrow">
      <div class="newsbox"></div>
      <div class="newsbox"></div>
      <div class="newsbox"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#666; padding: 10px;">1337 WHEEEH</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .newsrow {
   display:block;
  }
  .newsbox{
    display:flex;
  }
  .column {
  height:auto;
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3e5qksh/1/

Comment: Tried this, now they'll stay visable but the move out of screen instead of stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the .column in your stylesheet.
If you want to make this site more smoth you can add more media querys. I personally use them like this:

```
/*Responsive Design*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px){
.cardinhalt{
    width: calc(100% - 10px) !Important;
}
}
/*Responsive Design*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
.cardinhalt{
    width: calc(50% - 10px) !Important;
}
}
/*Responsive Design*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
.cardinhalt{
    width: calc(33.33% - 10px) !Important;
}
}
/*Responsive Design*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
.cardinhalt{
    width: calc(25% - 10px) !Important;
}
}
/*Responsive Design*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
.cardContainer{
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .column height did fix the problem after removing it. The boxes worked as soon as I entered some information into them.

Comment: No need to post this as an answer. You can comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: @ovokuro I know, but there were several people giving the same answer and the one who was first, I could not react on.